# PHP-Elasticsearch not returning all results like Kibana

Tags: php, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

We have configured ELK for our server logs.

We want to query elasticsearch using PHP. Below is our code:

```
//Change URL Accordingly
$elasticServer = ["172.29.106.202:9200"]; //Server IP / Name

//Create Elastic Search Object
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
        ->setHosts($elasticServer)
        ->setRetries(0)
        ->build();

$result = new stdClass();

$params = array();
$params['index'] = '*'; //search all index
$params['type'] = 'Beta Logs from 51.66';
$params['body']['query']['match']['message'] =  "Action:read_session";
$result->searches = $client->search($params);
```

This returns a set of data. But however, the data returned is not similar to what I get from Kibana UI.

**Update**

Below are the list of indices on my server:

```
health status index                         pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.24   5   1      57231            0     39.7mb         39.7mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.25   5   1     126438            0     41.2mb         41.2mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.26   5   1     109705            0     42.8mb         42.8mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.27   5   1     153558            0     52.2mb         52.2mb 
yellow open   .kibana                         1   1          2            0      9.6kb          9.6kb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.28   5   1     124439            0     38.8mb         38.8mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.29   5   1     136844            0     47.6mb         47.6mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.19   5   1      11535            0      3.6mb          3.6mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.30   5   1       2501            0      888kb          888kb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.31   5   1      63040            0     43.8mb         43.8mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.20   5   1      85636            0       27mb           27mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.21   5   1     108346            0     37.7mb         37.7mb 
yellow open   local-logstash-2016.05.11       5   1     667319            0    212.3mb        212.3mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.22   5   1     125687            0       44mb           44mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.08.01   5   1       3245            0      2.2mb          2.2mb 
yellow open   localbeta-logstash-2016.07.23   5   1      18437            0      5.5mb          5.5mb
```

Any explanation? or change in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your query to behave like Kibana, you need to use a `query_string` query like this:

```
$params = array();
$params['index'] = '*'; //search all index
$params['type'] = 'Beta Logs from 51.66';
$params['body']['query']['query_string']['query'] =  "Action:read_session";
$result->searches = $client->search($params);
```

Comment: Not working. are you sure with `['query']['query_string']['query']`

Comment: Do you get an error (if yes, please share) or no results?

Comment: I am getting results. But the results are not similar to that of Kibana Discover UI. Say, if in Kibana it returns 54 results, then it will only return near about 17 results from my php-code

Comment: Another observation to this, if I specify  `['index']` as a particular date and not as `*`. Then it returns more results.

Comment: Can you update your question with the list of indices you have?

Comment: Can you try with `$params['index'] = 'localbeta-*'`?

Comment: It gives the similar result. I have observed that `hits.total` is 54. But however the hits array has only 9 results.

Comment: It returns 10 hits by default. You can add `$params['body']['size'] = 100` is you want to retrieve more results at once.